# Need to load ng-model dynamically inside of a ng-repeat for radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, api

I need to load ng-model dynamically with data from an API call using ng-repeat for a series of radio buttons"

My Controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller('apiCallController', [$scope,'$http',function($scope,$http{

    $http.get(sampleUrl)
    .success(function(data){
    $scope.sampleData = animal
    });

}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class "row" ng-repeat="animal in animals">
  <div class="col-md-1>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="{{animal.Name}}" id="task1" value="true" ng-model="{{animal.ID}}">
       Yes
    </label> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="{{animal.Name}}" id="task1" value="false" ng-model="{{animal.ID}}">
       Yes
    </label> 
  </div>
</div>
```

When I load up the site, everything seems to show up properly, but when I check the console to see the value of ng-model it shows up as "{{animal.ID}}" instead of the value of animal.ID

Not sure what to do here.

Comment: Your code looks like it has a syntax error and some semantic errors -- try `apiCallController', ['$scope',`

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add single quotes around the interpolations:

```
<input type="radio" name="'{{animal.Name}}'" id="task1" value="true" ng-model="'{{animal.ID}}'">
```

Comment: I tried that.  It returns the right ID, but puts it in single and double quotes so instead of returning ng-model="value of id" it returns "'value of id'"

Answer (score 0):

Your code has

```
[$scope,'$http',
```

You are trying to inject a variable `$scope`, but when you use this format of dependency injection, you need to provide a string:

```
['$scope', '$http'
```